# Loading problems/possible bug

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have had a vault for a couple weeks now and I get to the main screen and click on the Vault # and the load screen starts but then freezes and kicks me back to my iPad home screen. Any ideas what it might be and or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you update the ipad? fallout shelter? I'm not sure if the game needs it but do you have an internet connection when this happens?

Comment: But @Aequitas. Fallout Shelter. It has no updates. *spooky noises*

Comment: What generation iPad are you using?

Comment: I had this problem on my iPhone 6 Plus. The only solution I could find was reinstalling the game, unfortunately.